# Xcode 12: How to fix the error 'archiveRootObject:toFile:' is deprecated

Tags: firebase, xcode12

I am using a beta of Xcode 12 (Version 12.0 beta (12A6159)). My project uses Firebase.
When I try to build it, some errors appears, like this one :

```
'archiveRootObject:toFile:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 - Use +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: and -writeToURL:options:error: instead
```

Xcode tells me to fix this problem in the folder "GoogleDataTransport", in a file at this line:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self toFile:[GDTCORStorage archivePath]];
```

I tried to follow stupidly what the error message tells me to do, so I started to write what the error says. I taped:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:<#(nonnull id)#> requiringSecureCoding:<#(BOOL)#> error:<#(NSError *__autoreleasing  _Nullable * _Nullable)#>];
```

I have no idea what I'm supposed to write to complete the blanks.
Would anyone have any idea?

Comment: I think you need to update the Firebase iOS SDK to the latest version, as this was fixed a while ago. You shouldn’t have to modify code inside the Firebase source code directly.

Comment: For a possible minimal implementation (untested): `NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self requiringSecureCoding:NO error:nil]; NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[GDTCORStorage archivePath]]; [data writeToURL:url options:0 error:nil];`But you better adopt the secure coding protocol and do some error handling.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Both solutions work, but they always bring me new errors (a lot) from the GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport folder. I think Google would have to update Firebase for the new Xcode 12.

Comment: Update firebase pod. In my case it is working after update pod file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if we update the Firebase SDK to the latest version, errors still appear (with Xcode 12 beta (12A6159)).
I reported this issue to Firebase Support. They told me it looks like a problem with CocoaPods.
However, they gave me a [workaround](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5987).

I will update this post when I have more informations.

Comment: have you found the solutiion to the problem yet? it has been a lot of months... Thanks in advance

Comment: @willscarter I forgot to share the "solution" on this post, thanks. Since I updated the pod file, I no longer have this issue... that is all I know about it. If you still have this issue, you should check the workaround I shared, it works well.